# Terminal $PATH error

Tags: terminal, path

I was adding a $PATH to `.bash_profile`:

```
PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin:$PATH"
```

So I could install PEAR on MAMP. That all worked, but now I have an this error each time I start up:

```
-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier
```

I tried a lot of solutions from people with similar problems, such as:

[I messed up my bash configuration on mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/11219/16529)

These are the files possibly containing the problem:

*/etc/profile*

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1) if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then eval /usr/libexec/path_helper -s` fi if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc fi`
```

*/etc/paths*

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

*~/.profile*

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH"
```

*~/.bash_profile*

```
#export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH"
```

*launchctl export*

```
    PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"; export PATH;
    TMPDIR="/var/folders/9l/7n7rrkrj0d51ydll3hb3l8780000gn/T/"; export TMPDIR;
    SHELL="/bin/bash"; export SHELL;
    HOME="/Users/XXXXXX"; export HOME;
    USER="XXXXXX"; export USER;
    LOGNAME="XXXXXX"; export LOGNAME;
    SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/tmp/launch-d3uaRv/Listeners"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
    Apple_Ubiquity_Message="/tmp/launch-YdytLh/Apple_Ubiquity_Message"; export Apple_Ubiquity_Message;
    Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/tmp/launch-8QgJZ0/Render"; export Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render;
    DISPLAY="/tmp/launch-c6nAQC/org.macosforge.xquartz:0"; export DISPLAY;
```

*printenv*

```
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
TMPDIR=/var/folders/9l/7n7rrkrj0d51ydll3hb3l8780000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-8QgJZ0/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=309
TERM_SESSION_ID=8336481B-7483-4050-919F-1268887775DE
USER=XXXXXX
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-d3uaRv/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-YdytLh/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:
PWD=/Users/XXXXXX
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/XXXXXX
LOGNAME=XXXXXX
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-c6nAQC/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
_=/usr/bin/printenv
OLDPWD=/Users/XXXXXX
```

Files in '/etc/paths.d/':

*40-XQuartz*

```
/opt/X11/bin
```

I dont have a  `bashrc` directory at location `/etc/bashrc`.

I also don't have `~/.bashrc`.

Maybe it is also useful that before I installed PEAR I added a `symlink` to `/usr/bin` maybe that is part of the problem?

Comment: I posted a possible solution. BTW, can you please modify your question by posting your entire `.bash_profile`? You can copy and past the result of `cat ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Hi! That is my entire '.bash_profile'. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Ok. It looks ok. Is `~/.profile` empty? Please try to comment the line you added in `~/.bash_profile` and copy and paste the result of `echo $PATH`

Comment: That's something really strange, how you can do `echo` if your `$PATH` is empty?

Comment: I updated and added the answer!

Comment: `/usr/bin` should be in your `$PATH`, as well as `/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: you can try to manually add them to your `PATH` by adding to `.bash_profile` the line `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH`

Comment: That is all set now. I still get the same error. I also tried removing the file but that also didn't make any difference.

Comment: Which file you removed?

Comment: I did this `/bin/mv .bash_profile bash_profile_disabled`

Comment: If you comment the line in `.bash_profile`, do you still have to do `/bin/mv` for moving a file or you can just use `mv`? If not, there is something wrong, because all the "shell commands" like `mv` are in `\bin` which should be in your `$PATH`

Comment: When I comment `.bash_profile` I can still use `mv` or `ls` etc

Comment: Hence your `$PATH` cannot be empty, however when you call the command `mv` from a directory different than `/bin`, it should return `-bash: mv: command not found`

Comment: Ah, when I comment now, this is my $PATH
`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:`

Comment: Good, that's look something like mine when I comment all my `.profile`. Now try to add the line I put in my answer to the file `.profile` and than `echo $PATH`

Comment: Did that, still having the same issue and `$PATH` is still returning the same thing

Comment: Did you cut&paste the "invalid identifier" message directly from Terminal or did you type it into the question manually?

Comment: It's a cut and paste!

Comment: Could you post the content of `/etc/paths`, each file in `/etc/paths.d/`, `/etc/bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` and the output of `launchctl export` and `printenv`? Do you use macports?

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question.
Is this what you mean with macports: http://www.macports.org/ ?

Comment: Yes, I meant that macports. But you just seem to have X11/XQuartz installed. I forgot to ask for the content of `~/.bash_login`, if there is such a file. Right now, are there any problems? The only strange thing that I see that the PATH in printenv should be grander because of the stuff in `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message you listed is the result of using one of

```
 export $VARIABLE
 export /a/path/to/something
 export *more or less anything which is not a syntactically correct variable name*
```

instead of

```
 export VARIABLE
```

in one of your initialization files. To find the offending line you need to look into all the `.profile`, `.bash_profile` and anything sourced/called from there and grep for 'export ' to find it.

As it seams to be related to the installation of either PEAR or MAMP I would start looking at any additions done by these installations.

Comment: The error message is clear enough. This is the correct answer, and forget all other voodoo.. Simply, you have somewhere an commands like: `VAR=/usr/local/bin ; export $VAR` (instead of `export VAR`). You can insert at the top of your .profile `set -x`, open new terminal window and see what is happening...

Comment: Thanks! Any more ideas where would I find the culprit? I looked into all listed files in this thread and can't find any instance that has  export $VAR instead of VAR

Comment: You also have to look in any files sourced/called from the standard files

Comment: for some reason when I did a `cat /etc/profile` now, I got :
'export PATH=$PATH: /usr/local/bin' on the final line

Which was causing the problem. Not sure who to give the answer to now.

Comment: @bottleboot, so just to be clear, the problem was a stray space on the line  'export PATH=$PATH: /usr/local/bin' which should have been  'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin'.  It had nothing to do with `export $VARIABLE`.

Comment: Yes that was it! Not sure how it got there and how it happened but that fixed the problems I had.

Comment: Good point, I've extended the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should add to your `.bash_profile` the following line instead of the one you reported in your question:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer! I'm still getting that error with the changes.

Comment: I think the ordering there is correct, however I would still advise quoting the lot.

Comment: @DannyStaple Do you mean keep the `"..."`?

Comment: Yes. I think so - if the original path expansion included other characters (okay I cannot see unescaped spaces working in the path), then you may not be including them in the assignment. General bash defensive coding...

Comment: @DannyStaple That's true, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me.
I gave the error because I wrote export $PATH=$PATH:<path> instead of export PATH=$PATH:<path>