# Terminal commands not found:

Tags: terminal, homebrew, path

**Short explanation.**

After I've created .bash_profile file and added the line **export PATH=/PATH/TO/YOUR/sbt/bin:$PATH** into it, my terminal stopped working properly. Could you please help me to fix the problem? [image]

**Long explanation.**
All I wanted and still want is to install Scala.
I followed this instruction:

> Mac OS X If you use the homebrew package manager, simply type brew
>   update and then brew install sbt in a Terminal prompt.
>
> Otherwise, install sbt by following these steps:
>
> - Download sbt from here: http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-native-packages/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.12.4/sbt.tgz
> - Unpack the archive to a directory of your choice
> - Add the bin/ directory to the PATH environment variable. Open the file ~/.bash_profile in an editor (create it if it doesn't exist) and
>     add the following line export PATH=/PATH/TO/YOUR/sbt/bin:$PATH
>
> Verify that sbt is installed correctly: Open a new terminal (to apply
>   the changed .bash_profile) using the Terminal application in
>   /Applications/Utilities/ and type sbt -h, you should see a help
>   message from sbt.

First, I tried it with Homebrew and followed [this instructions](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/setting-up-os-x-mavericks-and-homebrew/). It didn't work well, so I decided to go through the steps above. After I created the .bash_profile file and added the line **export PATH=/PATH/TO/YOUR/sbt/bin:$PATH** (with the valid path, of course), terminal went crazy. Your help is more than welcome!

**EDIT:**

Ina:sbt ps1$ echo $PATH

//Users/ps1/Documents/PS

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere? Can you run `echo $PATH` and paste the output of that.

Comment: I get //Users/ps1/Documents/PS

Comment: I don't have PS in Documents, only PS 1.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66931/terminal-path-error

Comment: echo $PATH prints now /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path includes spaces, you're going to need to quote it.

Your line `export PATH=/Users/ps1/Documents/PS 1/whatever-else/:$PATH` causes Bash to interpret the `PATH=/Users/ps1/Documents/PS` part as the full first argument to your PATH—telling `export` to set the PATH to only the section before the space. If you use `export "PATH=/Users/ps1/Documents/PS 1/whatever-else/:$PATH"`, it will interpret the entire `PATH=/Users/ps1/Documents/PS 1/whatever-else/:$PATH` as part of the first argument. By convention, most people only quote the right side of the equals sign, because it looks nicer, it's the only thing that needs quoted, and bash automatically concatenates strings with no spaces between them.

Comment: I see.. I managed to open the .bash_profile file and added the quotation marks. Unfortunately, I still see the following message when I open the terminal: 

Last login: Fri Oct 24 00:15:50 on ttys000
-bash: export: `“PATH=//Users/ps1/Documents/PS': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `1/sbt/bin:??': not a valid identifier

Comment: @Ina You have smart quotes. That does not work. You can just copy and paste from my post or use another editor like `nano` or `emacs`.

Comment: You are right. The problem is solved. THANK YOU! Now I just have to figure out why the command sbt -h prints a wrong message out.

Comment: This might be helpful for those who encounter the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819124/how-to-run-bash-profile-in-mac-terminal